# Why wont my app let me turn on tracing?

Tags: asp.net, trace

I have an asp.net application and when I try and turn on the application tracing....

```
 <system.web>
      <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Pages/Account/MyAlerts.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Pages/Account/FullDetails.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Pages/Account/ActivateLicence.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
```

I get the following error:

[image: arrrg no trace]

I have looked for

```
<deployment retail=true />
```

But its not in my config and I really cant see why when I navigate to mysite/trace.axd I get this error.

Comment: did you get final solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for inherited values from your,

1. machine.config - if you are using .NET framework 4 its in
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
2. Root web.config - if you are using .NET framework 4 its in
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
3. if your application configured as sub folder in IIS your web.config values might have been inherited from parent application.

   `<deployment retail=true />`  is typically used in production web servers in machine.config you can read more about config values inheritance from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx